# How to get parent node attribute through child node using minidom library in python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have the below xml structure, and I would like to get the testsuite tag attribute "name" based on the each testcase id.

*Sample xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <testsuite id="307849" name="Suppress Pending LOA" >
      <node_order><![CDATA[13]]></node_order>
      <details><![CDATA[]]></details> 
   <testsuite id="307850" name="Party Manager" >
      <node_order><![CDATA[0]]></node_order>
      <details><![CDATA[]]></details> 
   <testcase internalid="307851" name="Set default of “On”">
    <node_order><![CDATA[1]]></node_order>
    <externalid><![CDATA[22994]]></externalid>
    <fullexternalid><![CDATA[RLTOQA-22994]]></fullexternalid>
   </testcase>
   <testcase internalid="307858" name="Verify (LOA) workflow?&quot;">
    <node_order><![CDATA[2]]></node_order>
    <externalid><![CDATA[22995]]></externalid>
    <fullexternalid><![CDATA[RLTOQA-22995]]></fullexternalid>
   </testcase>
   </testsuite>
   <testsuite id="307871" name="Provisioning User" >
      <node_order><![CDATA[1]]></node_order>
      <details><![CDATA[]]></details> 
   <testcase internalid="307872" name="Set default of “On”">
   <node_order><![CDATA[1]]></node_order>
   <externalid><![CDATA[22998]]></externalid>
   <fullexternalid><![CDATA[RLTOQA-22998]]></fullexternalid>
   </testcase>
   <testcase internalid="307879" name="Verify Hover-over help text is?">
    <node_order><![CDATA[2]]></node_order>
    <externalid><![CDATA[22999]]></externalid>
    <fullexternalid><![CDATA[RLTOQA-22999]]></fullexternalid>
    </testcase>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite id="307882" name="SP Portal" >
       <node_order><![CDATA[2]]></node_order>
       <details><![CDATA[]]></details> 
    <testsuite id="307883" name="Orders" >
    <node_order><![CDATA[3]]></node_order>
    <details><![CDATA[]]></details> 
    <testsuite id="307884" name="New Orders" >
       <node_order><![CDATA[2]]></node_order>
       <details><![CDATA[]]></details> 
    <testcase internalid="307885" name=" Numbers: “LOA Workflow?” is set">
    <node_order><![CDATA[100]]></node_order>
    <externalid><![CDATA[23000]]></externalid>
    <fullexternalid><![CDATA[RLTOQA-23000]]></fullexternalid>
    </testcase>
    </testsuite>
    </testsuite>
    </testsuite>
    </testsuite>
```

In above example I would like to get the 307851 testcase internalid and parent testsuite name which is "Party Manager", and testcase internalid is 307885 and should return "New Order" as testsuite name. So, It needs to return the immediate parent node name attribute. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using minidom.

```
test_cases = doc.getElementsByTagName("testcase")

for test_case in test_cases:
    if test_case.getAttribute('internalid') == '307851':
        suite_name = test_case.parentNode.getAttribute('name')
        print suite_name
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure your need `minidom`?

From the docs:

> Users who are not already proficient with the DOM should consider
>   using the xml.etree.ElementTree module for their XML processing
>   instead.

So, it seems impossible with `minidom`.

Unfortunately, `xml.etree.ElementTree` also has no standard tool to getting parent from the element. But you can iterate over your elements and do whatever you want in pure python having you XML as simple as nested list (elements) and dicts (attributes).

The most simple solution - is use `lxml` third-party library, which provides `elem.getparent()` method and full XPath language support to quickly find desired `elem` with certain name and attributes.

Try something from these based on good official tutorials. GL!